# Unable to get responses from pusher when using private channels with no error messages

Tags: php, laravel, vue.js, pusher, laravel-echo

When using public channel, I do get the responses but the moment I change this to a private channel with the check in channels.php file returning true, I get no response and from pusher's side, it is clear that the message is getting there but laravel echo is not getting the response after that

Comment: how do you register the private channel? please show some code

Answer (score 0):

Hope my code will help you
Configure events

```
public function broadcastOn()
    {
        return new PrivateChannel('Chat.'. $this->chat->user_id.'.'.$this->chat->friend_id);
    }
```

add channel

```
 Broadcast::channel('Chat.{user_id}.{friend_id}', function ($user, 
  $user_id,$friend_id) {
    return $user->id == $friend_id;
 });
```

get data from this channel

```
axios.post('/chat/getchat/'+friendId).then((response)=>{
        this.chats = response.data;
      });
      Echo.private('Chat.'+friendId+'.'+userId)
      .listen('BroadcastChat',(e)=>{
        this.chats.push(e.chat);
      });
```